# facing issues while importing fbx file sequence

Tags: animation

I am facing issues importing the .fbx file sequence to create an animation. I tried a variety of different setting combinations while importing. Either only the selected file is imported or all the files are imported in the same frame (that is the objects that is supposed to be imported in separate frames are overlapping).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a vertex-based animation. The original files were exported from ParaView in .x3d format. It was further exported to .fbx format from Blender.  I am expecting the imported sequences to play as an animation.